# Load directly gz file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I have this [gz file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d18iqa21z2nxp8h/DCCV_OCCUPATIT%20-%20%20Employment%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20-%20Full%20dataset.gz?dl=0) from dati.istat.it: within it's a csv file (with different name) that i want load directly in pandas dataframe.

If i unzip with 7zip i easily load with this code
`pd.read_csv("DCCV_OCCUPATIT_Data+FootnotesLegend_175b2401-3654-4673-9e60-b300989088bb.csv", sep="|", engine = "python")`

how i can do it without unzip with 7zip frist?

thx a lot!

Comment: You can try add parameter `compression='gzip'` to `read_csv` or `compression='infer'`

Comment: Alternately to @jezrael, you can do the unzipping from within your Python script with the `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use library [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test/file.gz')
print pd.read_csv(z.open("DCCV_OCCUPATIT_Data+FootnotesLegend_175b2401-3654-4673-9e60-b300989088bb.csv"),
                  sep="|",
                  engine = "python")
```

Pandas supports only `gzip` and `bz2` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **compression** : {‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘infer’, None}, default ‘infer’
>
> For on-the-fly decompression of on-disk data. If ‘infer’, then use gzip or bz2 if filepath_or_buffer is a string ending in ‘.gz’ or ‘.bz2’, respectively, and no decompression otherwise. Set to None for no decompression.